# Grails 3 Accessing Grails domain constraints at runtime

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I used to access grails 2 constraints in my gsp like this :

```
${MyDomainClass.constraints.myProperty.inList.collect{it.name()}}
```

It doesn't work in Grails 3 anymore

Comment: OK that will be grailsApplication.getArtefact('Domain', 'MyDomainClass').getConstrainedProperties().myProperty.inList.collect{it.name()}

Comment: You should place your comment in an answer with a link to Grails documentation supporting the difference. That way future readers can find this answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails 3.0 domain and command objects are using the trait `grails.validation.Validateable` *(Source can be found [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.8/grails-plugin-validation/src/main/groovy/grails/validation/Validateable.groovy))*. That trait gives you access to the constraints by providing the following method.

```
static Map<String, ConstrainedProperty> getConstraintsMap();
```

In order to access the constraints you call that method on your domain or command object. The following example accesses the `nullable` constraint on a domain objects property called `day`.

```
domainObject.getConstraintsMap()['day']['nullable']
```

Comment: So from what I understand, for a domain class it will be  
`static Map<String, Constrained> getConstrainedProperties();`
according to the DomainClass trait:
[(source)](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.0.8/grails-plugin-domain-class/src/main/groovy/grails/artefact/DomainClass.groovy)

`domainObject.getConstrainedProperties()['day']['nullable']`.  
The `Validateable` trait is for command objects.

Answer (score 0):

That way, which was valid in Grails 2, still works...

```
grailsApplication.getArtefact('Domain',
    'MyDomainClass').getConstrainedProperties().myProperty.inList.collect{it.name()}
```

[see GrailsDomainClass API](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/core/GrailsDomainClass.html#getConstrainedProperties())

Comment: Actually the access changed in Grails 3 by introducing traits.